# Put the results of authenticate.js into a variable in a separate JS file

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to retrieve a token from a web service.

```
function authenticate($scope, $http) {
    var url="/identity/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials";
    var client_id="xxxxxxxxxx";
    var client_secret="N4KgVFAfjeFsTcFRTmg9h4ZR6KE08p3F";
    $http.get('https://'+url+'&client_id='+client_id+'&client_secret='+client_secret)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.token = data.access_token;
        });
}
```

And I can return this to my index.html with no issues.

```
<div ng-controller="authenticate">
{{token}}</div>
```

Now I want to use that {{token}} but in another.js file.

I can't work out the syntax to declare {{token}} as a variable in my JS. Similarly, I wonder if I need to make sure that another.js doesn't run until after authenticate.js.

I am attempting to build a simple internal web app to lookup data from our lead database.

Comment: you can do it by factory or service or rootscope

Comment: check this plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/yHTk2nJqE2gyuTmDhptZ?p=preview
that is just an idea

Comment: well, you can store the value of token in localStorage and check if the token is available in each route or state change and if there is no token, meaning no authentication, you can simply redirect the user to the login page.